# How to change the distance from the top of the page for the ToC, LoF and LoT?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, report

I'm trying to adjust the distance from the top of the page to the Table of Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables to the same distance as my chapter headings.
I'm writing in *\documentclass{report}*

I was able to minimize the chapter heading space as follows but am not sure how to apply that to my ToC, LoF and LoT and they currently all start almost one third down from the top of the page.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm,paperwidth=22cm,
    tmargin=25.4mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=38.1mm,rmargin=25.4mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%Remove Chapter numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% Show down to subsubsection
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{-20pt}% Just some value...
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{%
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed!}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Change the name of the TOC from Contents to Table of Contents
\addto\captionsenglish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    {Table of Contents}
}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\interlinepenalty=10000}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}

%format chapter heading distance from the top of the page
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\newpage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
Some text here

\newpage  
\chapter[CHAPTER 1: Introduction]{}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```